Why am l not able to successfully log in?
I am trying to login. If my details are correct, l am automatically redirected to the home page. The problem is every time l click login, it displays the error message that l entered an incorrect password. This means there is an issue with how l am trying to access the hashed password in the database. To be clear l used password_hash() to enter the password into the database.
<?php
session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION['id'])){
 $user_id = $_SESSION['id'];
}else {
 $user_id = '';
}

$message = [];

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    
    $email = trim($_POST['email']);
    $pass = trim($_POST['pass']);

    $user = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE email = ?");
    $user->execute([$email]);
    $row = $user->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    if($row) {
            if(password_verify($pass, $row['password'])){
                $_SESSION['id'] = $row['id'];
                header('location: home.php');
                exit();
            } else {
                $message[] = "Incorrect password";
            }
    } else {
            $message[] = "Email not found";
            
        }
}

?>


make sure the password field is large enough to store the hash data
